# How to see when Fragment Change to another fragment in Navigation Component

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

**Problem**

I have a BottomNavigationView in which I used  Navigation Component to display fragments. I need to check a condition every time the user clicks on an item in the BottomNavigationView. What would be the most correct way to do this using navigation components?

**What I did: (Is there a more efficient way to do this?)**

```
 val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragment)//this line I dont use it
 binding.bottomNav.setupWithNavController(navController) //this line I dont use it

binding.bottomNav.apply {
            setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
                if (it.itemId == R.id.homeFragment) {
                    if(theUserWasLogged()){
                        setFragment(new HomeFragment())
                    }else{
                        displayDialogLogIn()
                    }

                } else if (it.itemId == R.id.avisosFragment) {
                    
                    setFragment(new avisosFragment())
                }else{
                    displayDialogLogIn()
                }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement navigation using the navigation component inside your `setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener`, you should use navController and directly call your your destination id or action id defined in you navigation graph, in your case, replace the `setFragment()` with `navController.navigate()`, i.e.

```
setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
    if (it.itemId == R.id.homeFragment) {
        if(theUserWasLogged()){
            navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
        }else{
            displayDialogLogIn()
        }
    } else if (it.itemId == R.id.avisosFragment) {
        navController.navigate(R.id.avisosFragment)
    }else{
        displayDialogLogIn()
    }
}
```

and also I think can use `when` instead `if` to have more concise code

```
setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.homeFragment -> {
            if(theUserWasLogged()) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
            } else {
                displayDialogLogIn()
            }
        }
        R.id.avisosFragment -> navController.navigate(R.id.avisosFragment)
        else -> displayDialogLogIn()
    }
}
```